# Rails validate number of nested fields submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I have a form_for that creates a poll. The poll has many poll_options aka choices as nested attributes.

**Question** -- How can I validate the number of poll_options? It does not makes sense to have a poll with only 1 choice.

Here is my model:

```
class PollOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :poll_responses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_options,
    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['value'].blank? },
    allow_destroy: true

  validates :poll_options, length: {
    minimum: 1, too_short: "must be at least 2.",
    maximum: 5, too_long: "can be 5 at most."
  }
```

Here is my view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :poll_options do |poll_option| %>
  <%= render 'poll_option_fields', f: poll_option %>
<% end %>
```

The error that I get is related to my render line in the view:

```
exception reentered
```

I also tried this validation, but it neither worked, nor produced errors:

```
  def validates(value)
    if value.count < 1
      errors.add(:base, "must have at least 2 choices.")
    end
  end
```

UPDATE: here are my request params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6h+wZ+RUAOIp8iXFX0V9t0MSxTGtFHpe7PZS3fJeF3JejaIbAm2jidLyg0qYII26NYX+F1BH6FHWNCFJ7nzymQ==", "poll"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "active"=>"true", "question"=>"Example - Which of these do you like best?", "poll_options_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"a", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"value"=>"b", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"value"=>"c", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "3"=>{"value"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Save Poll", "controller"=>"polls", "action"=>"create"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate in the poll model, you can add a custom validation in `Poll` like this:

```
def validates_amount_of_polls
  if poll_options.size < 2
     errors.add(:base, "must have at least 2 choices")
  end
end
```

Comment: The `value` doesn't have anything to do with the custom validations, maybe you don't have it in the table. You should remove the `value` near to the `question` because only the poll option has it

Comment: Thank you. I got it working when I put it in poll and put `validate :validates_amount_of_poll_options` above it

Comment: Oh, maybe you put `validates` instead of `validate`. Mark it as correct if you think it is

Comment: if you change it to `.size` instead of count i will mark as correct. the `.count` was not working on `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<PollOption`

Comment: Changed, you're right, it isn't saved yet, so you can't go to the database